# google app engine upload for the first time

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm uploading my first application to GAE, but I keep getting a "This application does not exist" error. I created a project called test. And my yaml has "application: test". So I know the spelling isn't wrong. And I've tried --no_cookies and o_auth2 sign-ins. Does anyone have any suggestions? Are project id's (in the dev console) and app_id's the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Developers console at https://console.developers.google.com, you will see a list of projects as shown below:

[image]

Select the **PROJECT ID** as your application id and not the **PROJECT NAME**.

Answer (score 0):

use your project_id not project name from the dev console

X_X